# Yii2 Active Form custom message with Html tags

Tags: jquery, yii2, message, active-form

How do you create a Yii2 Active Form custom message using Html tags?
I change this message via `jQuery.activeForm`.

**Current message:**
[image]
**Desired message**
[image]

Here is the javascript code I am trying:
`myform.js` - which included to `AppAssets.php`.

The order of operations:

1. **On browser:** Validating email by jQuery
2. **On server:** Validating email, verifying email for existance, for bad users list and so ... - These functions are located in `ajax/is-email-busy` action. I do it via Ajax query
3. **On browser:** If this email is already registered and its email of good user, change message
4. **On browser:** When user clicks the link in message, will appear popup form to login

   ```
   $("#form-ad").on("afterValidateAttribute", function(event, attribute, messages) {
       var hasError = messages.length !== 0;
       var field = $(attribute.container);
       var input = field.find(attribute.input);

       if(attribute.name == 'email' && !hasError) {

           var form_data = new FormData();
           form_data.append('email', input.val());

           $.ajax({
                   url: 'ajax/is-email-busy',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false,
                   data: form_data,                         
                   type: 'post',
                   success: function(data) {
                       console.log(data);
                       jQuery('#form-ad')
                               .yiiActiveForm(
                               'updateAttribute',
                               'adform-email',
                               ['This email is busy. If it\'s your email <a href="#">click here</a>']);
                   }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

In a view file:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'email')->input('email');
```

Comment: please show the ecode (view and related model)  for tha current message /field / form

Comment: Solved. Replaced `jQuery('#form-ad').yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute'...` with `jQuery('#adform-email').next().append(data.message);`. This message I take from Ajax response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the error message of a rule by specifying the message property when declaring the rule, like the following,

in your active form model

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       ['email', 'required', 
         'message' => 'This email is busy. If it\'s your email 
             <a href="#">click here</a>'
      ],
      ['email', 'email'],
   ];
}
```

otherwise you don't want add a custom validation rule in Yii and you want use jquery you should refer to the proper field id 
normally the field id is modelname-fieldname (all lowercase) separated by `-`
In your case should by id='myform-email' and with this reference set the proper attribute (look ad the renderd code for find the correct attribute)

Looking at the code rendered by Yii2 the error message are managed by adding a div containing the text related to the message and hidden/display in function offer the result of validation. I suggest you the same behavior. When you validation fails add a sibling to the input with your message and the display. Or you can prepare this div in you form and then display in your jquery  validation code.

I hope this is useful

Comment: I've edited a question. This `require` condition is not enough in my case

Comment: which other condition you need?

Comment: I have added the validation form email type if you need more comment with your requirement.

Comment: One of them: checking for a bad user. I've described above

Comment: You can add custom validation rules without using jquery. otherwise you should chage the message too. with jquery ...but your reference to the field id  are wrong.

Comment: This is `email` attribute of my `User` model. I also use it to authenticate in main login page. Changing model attribute rules conflicts each other

Comment: Well if you need jquery /ajax custom validation then check the id for the field and the attr for the message look at the html code rendered in browser (tipically ctrl + U) and looking for the right reference..

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo with ids. There is `#form-ad` instead of  `#form-myform` . I haven't met errors with javascripts and showing simple message here, the **problem is inserting link tag inside of message** . I searched for Yii's jQuery function to fix this problem with messages. Is it good way to do it only by jQuery? Without using `.yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute'...` ?

Comment: I have analyzed the coder rendered by yii for message and i have update the answer. Is a simple but powerful solution...

Comment: Sorry for late response, I solved it myself, like your suggestion. Thanks )